# использовал ли человек мою флешку на комьютере?

Tags: windows, безопасность, драйвер, железо, реестр

Пытаюсь понять, пользовался ли человек моей флешкой на своем компьютере?

Установил спец.программу у него на компьютере, запусил её, затем воткнул свою флешку.

Первое подключение - это когда впервые флешку 08.05.2019 вставил так?

А переподключение 03.01.2019 это что? Как такое может быть? *Windows 10* у него стоит. Скрин приложил красным, обвел запись.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *установил спец.программу* Зря. *воткнул свою флешку* И потерял возможность определить требуемое. Сам виноват. *первое подключение - это когда впервые флешку 08.05.2019 вставил так? а переподключение 03.01.2019 это что?* А это читай маны на программу... хрен знает, чё она откель берёт и в какую колонку выводит... но что переподключение ДО первого подключения есть бред голимый - и без этого очевидно.

Comment: @Akina, Ну по скрину что можно сделать какой вывод то. Даты вроде как верны...

Comment: *по скрину что можно сделать какой вывод то* По-моему, никакого. Но если кто-то сделает какой-то вывод - я лично не против, я же ж могу и ошибиться.

Comment: Такая же фигня, моё предположение что просто колонки спутаны местами.

Comment: `Переподключение` - это сброшенное подключение, а потом вы воткнули и вот у вас и `Подключение`. Это уже говорит о том, подключали ранее `03.01.2019`, а вы подключили `08.05.2019`.